# Trying to find date based on jq

Tags: json, yaml, jq, home-assistant

In Home Assistant CLI, running `hassio snapshots list`, the output is as below, where I'm trying to locate the last date to keep in this output looking back 3 days (in the example list below this should be the date of 2020-01-24):

```
- date: "2019-12-10T03:00:01.313293+00:00"
  name: Automated backup 2019-12-10 04:00
  protected: false
  slug: a0d3f958
  type: full
- date: "2020-02-03T16:25:55.265219+00:00"
  name: Automated backup 2020-02-03 17:25
  protected: false
  slug: acb7907b
  type: full
- date: "2020-02-03T15:00:11.584836+00:00"
  name: Automated backup 2020-02-03 16:00
  protected: false
  slug: 6284d707
  type: full
- date: "2020-01-24T03:00:01.169351+00:00"
  name: Automated backup 2020-01-24 04:00
  protected: false
  slug: 53d10566
  type: full
```

Earlier this worked, but there has been a change and I can't resolve what is wrong now:

```
last_date_to_keep=$(hassio snapshots list | jq .data.snapshots[].date | sort -r | head -n "3" | tail -n 1 | xargs date -D "%Y-%m-%dT%T" +%s --date )
```

The output is:

```
zsh: no matches found: .data.snapshots[].date
date: option requires an argument: date
```

Comment: `jq` cannot read yaml file. Use `yq` instead

Comment: `yq` is not part of HA default installation, and I can't rely on 3.rd party installation.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to your problem using `awk` and `date` command:

```
awk -v ref=$(date "+%s" -d "3 days ago") '
    /^- date: /{t=mktime(gensub(/[-"T:]|\.[0-9+:"]*/," ","G",$3));} t>ref' file
```

This relies on awk `mktime` function that converts the string date into the unix timestamp.
The `gensub` function formats the date into the format needed by `mktime`.

The variable `ref` is set to the date reference given by the `date` command.

Comment: could you please provide an example to resolve my CLI line above?

Answer (score 0):

With your input, using the Python-based yq (https://kislyuk.github.io/yq):

```
yq '.[].date'
```

produces:

```
"2019-12-10T03:00:01.313293+00:00"
"2020-02-03T16:25:55.265219+00:00"
"2020-02-03T15:00:11.584836+00:00"
"2020-01-24T03:00:01.169351+00:00"
```

You can also run the (reverse) sorting and selection in the same run of yq, e.g.

```
yq 'map(.date) | sort | reverse[-2] | .[0:10]' hassio.txt 
"2020-01-24"
```

#### Alternatives

- yaml2json with jq

  `yaml2json hassio.txt | jq 'map(.date) | sort | reverse[-2] | .[0:10]'`
- Go version of yq

  `yq r hassio.txt '[*].date'`

  produces a listing of the "date" fields.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, `yq` are unfortunately not part of default HA installation, and because of this I can't use it as I can't rely on 3.rd party installations.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an only-jq solution, which of course comes with the kinds of caveats as any proposed solution that views that YAML as text:

```
< hassio.txt jq -nR '
  [inputs | select(test("^- date")) | sub(".*date: ";"") | fromjson]
  | sort | reverse[-2] | sub("\\..*";"")'
"2020-01-24T03:00:01"
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I'm still to novice to fully understand how to replace your suggestion with the previous `last_date_to_keep=$(hassio snapshots list | jq .data.snapshots[].date | sort -r | head -n "3" | tail -n 1 | xargs date -D "%Y-%m-%dT%T" +%s --date )`